# Moving list elements using up and down buttons in a circular way

Tags: jquery, html

I have a unsorted list and each element can be moved up and down by clicking his up or down button. Witch is working fine.

I would like this list to be circular. Ex : if the up button of line_1 is clicked line_1 moves at the end of the list or if the down button of line_3 is clicked line_3 moves at the beginning of the list.

I have tried this but the first line won't move to the end of the list :

```
$('.up').click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).parent.is(':first'))
            $(this).parent.insertAfter($(this).parent.siblings().last());
        else
            $(this).parent.insertBefore($(this).parent.prev());
    }
);
```

My list :

```
<ul>
    <li>line_1
        <button class="up">up</button>
        <button class="down">down</button>
    </li>
    <li>line_2
        <button class="up">up</button>
        <button class="down">down</button>
    </li>
    <li>line_3
        <button class="up">up</button>
        <button class="down">down</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my jquery code :

```
$('.up').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
});

$('.down').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
});
```

How can I make the list circular ?

[Here is a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ionmang20/ff8t9dqx/)

Comment: only one up and down  is enough .. is it . why this many buttons to make it complex

Comment: yes, you are right, but it's not up to me so each line has to have a up and down button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it - you're looking for the `:first-child` selector, not the `:first`.

Also, to improve speed and readability, I recommend caching your jQuery references to the list item so that the DOM doesn't need to be traversed for every reference to the button's parent. Here's how I wrote your code:

```
var $ul = $('ul')

$('.up').click(function () {
    var $li = $( this ).parent();

    if ( $li.is(':first-child') )
        $ul.append($li);
    else 
        $li.insertBefore($li.prev());
});

$('.down').click(function () {
    var $li = $( this ).parent();

    if ( $li.is(':last-child') )
        $ul.prepend( $li );        
    else
        $li.insertAfter($li.next());
});
```